Dynamic type instantiation of Local class in Python 3.7
I'm trying to do some custom serialization/deserialization and must be able to handle custom data-classes, even local ones within functions. I found a question about this with a proper solution, but this works only for non-locals/nested classes.
Example Code.
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Foo:
    def bar(self) -> None:
        @dataclass
        class TestClass:
            val1: str
            val2: int

        instance = TestClass("", 1)
        print(type(instance))

test = Foo()
test.bar()
print(type(test))

This snippet gives me this output:
<class '__main__.Foo.bar.<locals>.TestClass'>
<class '__main__.Foo'>

When trying to retrieve the type from the given string, this works for the class Foo, but not for Foo.bar.<locals>.TestClass:
module = __import__("python_typing_example")
foo_type = getattr(module, "Foo") # <-- Works fine
test_class_type = getattr(module, "Foo.bar.<locals>.TestClass") # <-- Gives AttributeError

Is there a solution to find local types within other classes/methods which have a local scope?

TestClass is a symbol scoped to within the bar function. Logically speaking it only exists while that method is being executed, and doesn't exist when it isn't. There's no reasonable way to access it from outside the function.

Not to mention that getattr doesn't accept dot-separated nested names. You'd need to do getattr(getattr(module, 'Foo'), 'bar') etc.

I agree on both comments. Nevertheless, when I call
module = __import__("python_typing_example") and test_class_type = getattr(getattr(getattr(module, "Foo"), "bar"), "<locals>")  inside the bar method I still get an attribute error. Any hints why this happens (works for the bar method)?

Yeah, again, that's what my entire first comment is about. The class assumes the ...<locals>... name because it has to assume some name. Doesn't mean it'll be accessible under that name.

You can use the dill package, which offers the capability to serialize and deserialize a dynamically generated class by saving and restoring the state of an interpreter session. So instead of restoring the dynamically generated class from its string representation of <class '__main__.Foo.bar.<locals>.TestClass'> you can deserialize the class from the serialized output of dill.dumps:
import dill
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Foo:
    def bar(self) -> None:
        @dataclass
        class TestClass:
            val1: str
            val2: int

        instance = TestClass("", 1)
        return dill.dumps(type(instance))

test = Foo()
print(test.bar())

This produces the serialized class as a bytestring:
b'\x80\x04\x95=\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\ndill._dill\x94\x8c\x0c_create_type\x94\x93\x94(h\x00\x8c\n_load_type\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x04type\x94\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\tTestClass\x94h\x04\x8c\x06object\x94\x85\x94R\x94\x85\x94}\x94(\x8c\n__module__\x94\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x0f__annotations__\x94}\x94(\x8c\x04val1\x94h\x04\x8c\x03str\x94\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x04val2\x94h\x04\x8c\x03int\x94\x85\x94R\x94u\x8c\x07__doc__\x94\x8c\x1fTestClass(val1: str, val2: int)\x94\x8c\x14__dataclass_params__\x94\x8c\x0bdataclasses\x94\x8c\x10_DataclassParams\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94N}\x94(\x8c\x04init\x94\x88\x8c\x04repr\x94\x88\x8c\x02eq\x94\x88\x8c\x05order\x94\x89\x8c\x0bunsafe_hash\x94\x89\x8c\x06frozen\x94\x89\x8c\nmatch_args\x94\x88\x8c\x07kw_only\x94\x89\x8c\x05slots\x94\x89\x8c\x0cweakref_slot\x94\x89u\x86\x94b\x8c\x14__dataclass_fields__\x94}\x94(h\x12h\x1d\x8c\x05Field\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94N}\x94(\x8c\x04name\x94h\x12h\x05h\x15\x8c\x07default\x94cdataclasses\nMISSING\n\x8c\x0fdefault_factory\x94cdataclasses\nMISSING\nh#\x88\x8c\x04hash\x94Nh"\x88\x8c\x07compare\x94\x88\x8c\x08metadata\x94h\x04\x8c\x10MappingProxyType\x94\x85\x94R\x94}\x94\x85\x94R\x94h)\x89\x8c\x0b_field_type\x94cdataclasses\n_FIELD\nu\x86\x94bh\x16h0)\x81\x94N}\x94(h3h\x16h\x05h\x19h4cdataclasses\nMISSING\nh5cdataclasses\nMISSING\nh#\x88h6Nh"\x88h7\x88h8h>h)\x89h?cdataclasses\n_FIELD\nu\x86\x94bu\x8c\x08__init__\x94h\x00\x8c\x10_create_function\x94\x93\x94(h\x00\x8c\x0c_create_code\x94\x93\x94(C\x04\x02\x01\x0c\x01\x94K\x03K\x00K\x00K\x03K\x02K\x13C\x1c\x95\x00X\x10l\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X l\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00g\x00\x94N\x85\x94h\x12h\x16\x86\x94\x8c\x04self\x94h\x12h\x16\x87\x94\x8c\x08<string>\x94hD\x8c\x1f__create_fn__.<locals>.__init__\x94K\x02C\x0c\x80\x00\xd8\x0c\x10\x84)\xd8\x0c\x10\x85)\x94C\x00\x94))t\x94R\x94c__builtin__\n__main__\nhDNNt\x94R\x94}\x94}\x94(h\x10}\x94(h\x12h\x15h\x16h\x19\x8c\x06return\x94Nu\x8c\x0c__qualname__\x94\x8c#Foo.bar.<locals>.TestClass.__init__\x94u\x86\x94b\x8c\x0b__replace__\x94hF(hH(C\x1a\x02\x07B\x02&\x01\x04\x02"\x02\x1e\x012\x03\x04\x02"\x01L\x014\x02F\xef\x04\x18\x94K\x01K\x01K\x00K\x03K\x06K\x0bB\xf4\x01\x00\x00\x95\x00[\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x00[\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x005\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00R\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x005\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00H\xc5\x00\x00n\x02U\x02R\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00[\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00L\x00a\x02\x00\x00M\x18\x00\x00U\x02R\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00d*\x00\x00U\x02R\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x01;\x00a\x19\x00\x00[\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00S\x01U\x02R\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00S\x023\x035\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00e\x01MS\x00\x00U\x02R\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x01;\x01d\x02\x00\x00Md\x00\x00U\x02R\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00[\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00L\x00a-\x00\x00U\x02R\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00[\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00L\x00a\x1a\x00\x00[\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00S\x03U\x02R\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00<\x02\x0e\x00S\x043\x035\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00e\x01[\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X\x02R\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x005\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X\x12R\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\'\x00\x00\x00M\xc7\x00\x00\x0b\x00 \x00U\x00R\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"\x00S\x050\x00U\x01D\x016\x01$\x00\x94(N\x8c\x06field \x94\x8cC is declared with init=False, it cannot be specified with replace()\x94\x8c\x08InitVar \x94\x8c! must be specified with replace()\x94)t\x94(\x8c\x07getattr\x94\x8c\x07_FIELDS\x94\x8c\x06values\x94h?\x8c\x0f_FIELD_CLASSVAR\x94h"h3\x8c\tTypeError\x94\x8c\x0e_FIELD_INITVAR\x94h4\x8c\x07MISSING\x94\x8c\t__class__\x94t\x94hM\x8c\x07changes\x94\x8c\x01f\x94\x87\x94\x8c\x1fc:\\Python313\\Lib\\dataclasses.py\x94\x8c\x08_replace\x94hsM#\x06C\xdb\x80\x00\xf4\x0e\x00\x0e\x15\x90T\x9c7\xd3\r#\xd7\r*\xd1\r*\xd3\r,\xf2\x00\x11\x054\x88\x01\xe0\x0b\x0c\x8f=\x89=\x9cO\xd2\x0b+\xd9\x0c\x14\xe0\x0f\x10\x8fv\x8fv\xe0\x0f\x10\x8fv\x89v\x98\x17\xd2\x0f \xdc\x16\x1f\xa0&\xa8\x11\xaf\x16\xa9\x16\xa8\x08\xf0\x00\x021,\xf0\x00\x02!-\xf3\x00\x02\x17.\xf0\x00\x02\x11.\xf1\x06\x00\r\x15\xe0\x0b\x0c\x8f6\x896\x98\x17\xd4\x0b \xd8\x0f\x10\x8f}\x89}\xa4\x0e\xd2\x0f.\xb01\xb79\xb19\xc4\x07\xd23G\xdc\x16\x1f\xa0(\xa81\xaf6\xa96\xa9*\xf0\x00\x015C\x01\xf0\x00\x01!D\x01\xf3\x00\x01\x17E\x01\xf0\x00\x01\x11E\x01\xe4\x1e%\xa0d\xafF\xa9F\xd3\x1e3\x88G\x97F\x91F\x8bO\xf1#\x11\x054\xf00\x00\x0c\x10\x8f>\x8a>\xd1\x0b$\x98G\xd1\x0b$\xd0\x04$\x94hR))t\x94R\x94cdataclasses\n__dict__\nhsNNt\x94R\x94}\x94}\x94(h\x10}\x94h[\x8c#Foo.bar.<locals>.TestClass._replace\x94u\x86\x94b\x8c\x08__repr__\x94hF(hH(C\x12\x04\x02@\x01\n\x01\x02\x01"\x01\x02\x01\x10\x02"\x01\x06\xff\x94K\x01K\x00K\x00K\x03K\x05K\x13C\xd6>\x02\x95\x00[\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x005\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00[\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00R\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"\x005\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004\x02n\x01U\x01T\x03;\x00a\x01\x00\x00g\x01T\x03R\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x015\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x1e\x00T\x04"\x00U\x005\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00n\x02T\x03R\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x015\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00U\x02$\x00!\x00T\x03R\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x015\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00f\x00=\x03\x1f\x00f\x01\x94N\x8c\x03...\x94\x86\x94(\x8c\x02id\x94\x8c\x07_thread\x94\x8c\tget_ident\x94\x8c\x03add\x94\x8c\x07discard\x94t\x94hM\x8c\x03key\x94\x8c\x06result\x94\x87\x94hr\x8c\x07wrapper\x94\x8c _recursive_repr.<locals>.wrapper\x94K\xffCg\xf8\x80\x00\xe4\x0e\x10\x90\x14\x8bh\x9c\x07\xd7\x18)\xd2\x18)\xd3\x18+\xd0\x0e+\x88\x03\xd8\x0b\x0e\x90,\xd2\x0b\x1e\xd8\x13\x18\xd8\x08\x14\xd7\x08\x18\xd1\x08\x18\x98\x13\xd4\x08\x1d\xf0\x02\x03\t&\xd9\x15"\xa04\xd3\x15(\x88F\xe0\x0c\x18\xd7\x0c \xd1\x0c \xa0\x13\xd4\x0c%\xd8\x0f\x15\x88\r\xf8\xf0\x03\x00\r\x19\xd7\x0c \xd1\x0c \xa0\x13\xd5\x0c%\xfa\x94C\x0b\xba\x08A\x15\x00\xc1\x15\x13A(\x03\x94\x8c\x0crepr_running\x94\x8c\ruser_function\x94\x86\x94)t\x94R\x94}\x94\x8c\x08__name__\x94h\x0fsh~Nh\x00\x8c\x0c_create_cell\x94\x93\x94N\x85\x94R\x94h\x98N\x85\x94R\x94\x86\x94t\x94R\x94}\x94\x8c\x0b__wrapped__\x94hF(hH(C\x02\x02\x01\x94K\x01K\x00K\x00K\x01K\x06K\x13Cl\x95\x00U\x00R\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00R\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00S\x01U\x00R\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00<\x02\x0e\x00S\x02U\x00R\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00<\x02\x0e\x00S\x033\x06$\x00\x94(N\x8c\x06(val1=\x94\x8c\x07, val2=\x94\x8c\x01)\x94t\x94(hmh[h\x12h\x16t\x94hM\x85\x94hOh~\x8c\x1f__create_fn__.<locals>.__repr__\x94K\x02C.\x80\x00\xd8\x0c\x10\x8fN\x89N\xd7\x0c\'\xd1\x0c\'\xd0\x0b(\xa8\x06\xa8t\xafy\xa9y\xa9m\xb87\xc04\xc79\xc19\xc1-\xc8q\xd0\tQ\xd0\x02Q\x94hR))t\x94R\x94c__builtin__\n__main__\nh~NNt\x94R\x94}\x94}\x94(h\x10}\x94h[h\xaau\x86\x94bs}\x94(h\x10h\xb2h[\x8c#Foo.bar.<locals>.TestClass.__repr__\x94u\x86\x94bh\x95(h\x96h\x1dh\x1aN\x8c\x0b__package__\x94\x8c\x00\x94\x8c\n__loader__\x94\x8c\x1a_frozen_importlib_external\x94\x8c\x10SourceFileLoader\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94(h3h\x1d\x8c\x04path\x94hrub\x8c\x08__spec__\x94\x8c\x11_frozen_importlib\x94\x8c\nModuleSpec\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94(h3h\x1d\x8c\x06loader\x94h\xbd\x8c\x06origin\x94hr\x8c\x0cloader_state\x94N\x8c\x1asubmodule_search_locations\x94N\x8c\x19_uninitialized_submodules\x94]\x94\x8c\r_set_fileattr\x94\x88\x8c\x07_cached\x94\x8c8c:\\Python313\\Lib\\__pycache__\\dataclasses.cpython-313.pyc\x94\x8c\r_initializing\x94\x89ub\x8c\x08__file__\x94hr\x8c\n__cached__\x94h\xce\x8c\x0c__builtins__\x94cbuiltins\n__dict__\n\x8c\x02re\x94h\x00\x8c\x0e_import_module\x94\x93\x94h\xd3\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x03sys\x94h\xd5\x8c\x03sys\x94\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x04copy\x94h\xd5h\xdc\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x05types\x94h\xd5h\xdf\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x07inspect\x94h\xd5h\xe2\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x07keyword\x94h\xd5h\xe5\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\tfunctools\x94h\xd5h\xe8\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\titertools\x94h\xd5h\xeb\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x03abc\x94h\xd5h\xee\x85\x94R\x94h\x84h\xd5h\x84\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x0cFunctionType\x94h\x04\x8c\nLambdaType\x94\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x0cGenericAlias\x94h\xdf\x8c\x0cGenericAlias\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x07__all__\x94]\x94(\x8c\tdataclass\x94\x8c\x05field\x94h/\x8c\x13FrozenInstanceError\x94\x8c\x07InitVar\x94\x8c\x07KW_ONLY\x94hl\x8c\x06fields\x94\x8c\x06asdict\x94\x8c\x07astuple\x94\x8c\x0emake_dataclass\x94\x8c\x07replace\x94\x8c\x0cis_dataclass\x94eh\xfeh\x1dh\xfe\x93\x94\x8c\x1a_HAS_DEFAULT_FACTORY_CLASS\x94h\x1dj\x08\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x14_HAS_DEFAULT_FACTORY\x94cdataclasses\n_HAS_DEFAULT_FACTORY\n\x8c\r_MISSING_TYPE\x94h\x1dj\x0b\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94hlcdataclasses\nMISSING\n\x8c\r_KW_ONLY_TYPE\x94h\x1dj\r\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94j\x00\x01\x00\x00cdataclasses\nKW_ONLY\n\x8c\x0f_EMPTY_METADATA\x94h>\x8c\x0b_FIELD_BASE\x94h\x1dj\x10\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x06_FIELD\x94cdataclasses\n_FIELD\nhicdataclasses\n_FIELD_CLASSVAR\nhkcdataclasses\n_FIELD_INITVAR\nhgh-\x8c\x07_PARAMS\x94h\x1c\x8c\x0f_POST_INIT_NAME\x94\x8c\r__post_init__\x94\x8c\x15_MODULE_IDENTIFIER_RE\x94h\xd3\x8c\x08_compile\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x1b^(?:\\s*(\\w+)\\s*\\.)?\\s*(\\w+)\x94K \x86\x94R\x94\x8c\r_ATOMIC_TYPES\x94(h\x07h\x04\x8c\x08property\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x04\x8c\x07complex\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x15h\x04\x8c\x0cEllipsisType\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x04\x8c\x05float\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x19h\x04\x8c\x08CodeType\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x04\x8c\x04bool\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x04\x8c\x12NotImplementedType\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x04\x8c\x08NoneType\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x04\x8c\x11BuiltinMethodType\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\xf6h\x04\x8c\x05range\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x04\x8c\x05bytes\x94\x85\x94R\x94\x91\x94\x8c\x0f_recursive_repr\x94h\x1dj?\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94h\xffh\x1dh\xff\x93\x94h/h0h\x1eh\x1fh\xfdh\x1dh\xfd\x93\x94\x8c\x15_fields_in_init_order\x94h\x1djC\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\n_tuple_str\x94h\x1djE\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\n_create_fn\x94h\x1djG\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\r_field_assign\x94h\x1djI\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0b_field_init\x94h\x1djK\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0b_init_param\x94h\x1djM\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x08_init_fn\x94h\x1djO\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x08_repr_fn\x94h\x1djQ\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x14_frozen_get_del_attr\x94h\x1djS\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x07_cmp_fn\x94h\x1djU\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x08_hash_fn\x94h\x1djW\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0c_is_classvar\x94h\x1djY\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0b_is_initvar\x94h\x1dj[\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0b_is_kw_only\x94h\x1dj]\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x08_is_type\x94h\x1dj_\xsh_set_none\x94h\x1djg\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\t_hash_add\x94h\x1dji\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0f_hash_exception\x94h\x1djk\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0c_hash_action\x94}\x94((\x89\x89\x88\x88\x88t\x94N(\x88\x89\x89\x89t\x94jj\x01\x00\x00(\x88\x89\x89\x88t\x94jl\x01\x00\x00(\x88\x89\x88\x89t\x94jj\x01\x00\x00(\x88\x89\x88\x88t\x94jl\x01\x00\x00(\x88\x88\x89\x89t\x94jj\x01\x00\x00(\x88\x88\x89\x88t\x94jl\x01\x00\x00(\x88\x88\x88\x89t\x94jj\x01\x00\x00(\x88\x88\x88\x88t\x94jl\x01\x00\x00u\x8c\x0e_process_class\x94h\x1dj\x7f\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x13_dataclass_getstate\x94h\x1dj\x81\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x13_dataclass_setstate\x94h\x1dj\x83\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\n_get_slots\x94h\x1dj\x85\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\n_add_slots\x94h\x1dj\x87\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94h\xfch\x1dh\xfc\x93\x94j\x01\x01\x00\x00h\x1dj\x01\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x16_is_dataclass_instance\x94h\x1dj\x8b\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94j\x06\x01\x00\x00h\x1dj\x06\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94j\x02\x01\x00\x00h\x1dj\x02\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\r_asdict_inner\x94h\x1dj\x8f\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94j\x03\x01\x00\x00h\x1dj\x03\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0e_astuple_inner\x94h\x1dj\x92\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94j\x04\x01\x00\x00h\x1dj\x04\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94j\x05\x01\x00\x00h\x1dj\x05\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94hshxu0\x8c\x06__eq__\x94hF(hH(C\x06\x02\x012\x01r\x01\x94K\x02K\x00K\x00K\x02K\x02K\x13C\xb2\x95\x00U\x01R\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x00R\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00L\x00a9\x00\x00U\x00R\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x01R\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:H\x00\x00=\x01(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00a\x19\x00\x00 \x00U\x00R\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x01R\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:H\x00\x00$\x00[\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00$\x00\x94N\x85\x94(hmh\x12h\x16\x8c\x0eNotImplemented\x94t\x94hM\x8c\x05other\x94\x86\x94hOj\x96\x01\x00\x00\x8c\x1d__create_fn__.<locals>.__eq__\x94K\x02C=\x80\x00\xd8\x05\n\x87_\x81_\x98\x04\x9f\x0e\x99\x0e\xd2\x05&\xd8\n\x0e\x8f)\x89)\x90U\x97Z\x91Z\xd1\n\x1f\xd7\n9\xa0D\xa7I\xa1I\xa8u\xafz\xa9z\xd1$9\xd0\x039\xdc\t\x17\xd0\x02\x17\x94hR))t\x94R\x94c__builtin__\n__main__\nj\x96\x01\x00\x00NNt\x94R\x94}\x94}\x94(h\x10}\x94h[\x8c!Foo.bar.<locals>.TestClass.__eq__\x94u\x86\x94b\x8c\x08__hash__\x94N\x8c\x0e__match_args__\x94h\x12h\x16\x86\x94ut\x94R\x94\x8c\x08builtins\x94\x8c\x07getattr\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x04dill\x94\x8c\x05_dill\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x08_setattr\x94j\xae\x01\x00\x00\x8c\x07setattr\x94\x93\x94\x87\x94R\x94h\x9c\x8c\rcell_contents\x94h\xaf\x87\x94R0j\xb8\x01\x00\x00h\x9aj\xb9\x01\x00\x00\x8f\x94\x87\x94R0j\xb6\x01\x00\x00j\xad\x01\x00\x00h[\x8c\x1aFoo.bar.<locals>.TestClass\x94\x87\x94R0.'

And then in a separate session you can reconstruct the dynamically generated class by calling dill.loads with the bytestring:
import dill

print(dill.loads(b'\x80\x04\x95=\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\ndill._dill\x94\x8c\x0c_create_type\x94\x93\x94(h\x00\x8c\n_load_type\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x04type\x94\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\tTestClass\x94h\x04\x8c\x06object\x94\x85\x94R\x94\x85\x94}\x94(\x8c\n__module__\x94\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x0f__annotations__\x94}\x94(\x8c\x04val1\x94h\x04\x8c\x03str\x94\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x04val2\x94h\x04\x8c\x03int\x94\x85\x94R\x94u\x8c\x07__doc__\x94\x8c\x1fTestClass(val1: str, val2: int)\x94\x8c\x14__dataclass_params__\x94\x8c\x0bdataclasses\x94\x8c\x10_DataclassParams\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94N}\x94(\x8c\x04init\x94\x88\x8c\x04repr\x94\x88\x8c\x02eq\x94\x88\x8c\x05order\x94\x89\x8c\x0bunsafe_hash\x94\x89\x8c\x06frozen\x94\x89\x8c\nmatch_args\x94\x88\x8c\x07kw_only\x94\x89\x8c\x05slots\x94\x89\x8c\x0cweakref_slot\x94\x89u\x86\x94b\x8c\x14__dataclass_fields__\x94}\x94(h\x12h\x1d\x8c\x05Field\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94N}\x94(\x8c\x04name\x94h\x12h\x05h\x15\x8c\x07default\x94cdataclasses\nMISSING\n\x8c\x0fdefault_factory\x94cdataclasses\nMISSING\nh#\x88\x8c\x04hash\x94Nh"\x88\x8c\x07compare\x94\x88\x8c\x08metadata\x94h\x04\x8c\x10MappingProxyType\x94\x85\x94R\x94}\x94\x85\x94R\x94h)\x89\x8c\x0b_field_type\x94cdataclasses\n_FIELD\nu\x86\x94bh\x16h0)\x81\x94N}\x94(h3h\x16h\x05h\x19h4cdataclasses\nMISSING\nh5cdataclasses\nMISSING\nh#\x88h6Nh"\x88h7\x88h8h>h)\x89h?cdataclasses\n_FIELD\nu\x86\x94bu\x8c\x08__init__\x94h\x00\x8c\x10_create_function\x94\x93\x94(h\x00\x8c\x0c_create_code\x94\x93\x94(C\x04\x02\x01\x0c\x01\x94K\x03K\x00K\x00K\x03K\x02K\x13C\x1c\x95\x00X\x10l\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X l\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00g\x00\x94N\x85\x94h\x12h\x16\x86\x94\x8c\x04self\x94h\x12h\x16\x87\x94\x8c\x08<string>\x94hD\x8c\x1f__create_fn__.<locals>.__init__\x94K\x02C\x0c\x80\x00\xd8\x0c\x10\x84)\xd8\x0c\x10\x85)\x94C\x00\x94))t\x94R\x94c__builtin__\n__main__\nhDNNt\x94R\x94}\x94}\x94(h\x10}\x94(h\x12h\x15h\x16h\x19\x8c\x06return\x94Nu\x8c\x0c__qualname__\x94\x8c#Foo.bar.<locals>.TestClass.__init__\x94u\x86\x94b\x8c\x0b__replace__\x94hF(hH(C\x1a\x02\x07B\x02&\x01\x04\x02"\x02\x1e\x012\x03\x04\x02"\x01L\x014\x02F\xef\x04\x18\x94K\x01K\x01K\x00K\x03K\x06K\x0bB\xf4\x01\x00\x00\x95\x00[\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x00[\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x005\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00R\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x005\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00H\xc5\x00\x00n\x02U\x02R\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00[\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00L\x00a\x02\x00\x00M\x18\x00\x00U\x02R\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00d*\x00\x00U\x02R\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x01;\x00a\x19\x00\x00[\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00S\x01U\x02R\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00S\x023\x035\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00e\x01MS\x00\x00U\x02R\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x01;\x01d\x02\x00\x00Md\x00\x00U\x02R\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00[\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00L\x00a-\x00\x00U\x02R\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00[\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00L\x00a\x1a\x00\x00[\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00S\x03U\x02R\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00<\x02\x0e\x00S\x043\x035\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00e\x01[\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X\x02R\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x005\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X\x12R\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\'\x00\x00\x00M\xc7\x00\x00\x0b\x00 \x00U\x00R\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"\x00S\x050\x00U\x01D\x016\x01$\x00\x94(N\x8c\x06field \x94\x8cC is declared with init=False, it cannot be specified with replace()\x94\x8c\x08InitVar \x94\x8c! must be specified with replace()\x94)t\x94(\x8c\x07getattr\x94\x8c\x07_FIELDS\x94\x8c\x06values\x94h?\x8c\x0f_FIELD_CLASSVAR\x94h"h3\x8c\tTypeError\x94\x8c\x0e_FIELD_INITVAR\x94h4\x8c\x07MISSING\x94\x8c\t__class__\x94t\x94hM\x8c\x07changes\x94\x8c\x01f\x94\x87\x94\x8c\x1fc:\\Python313\\Lib\\dataclasses.py\x94\x8c\x08_replace\x94hsM#\x06C\xdb\x80\x00\xf4\x0e\x00\x0e\x15\x90T\x9c7\xd3\r#\xd7\r*\xd1\r*\xd3\r,\xf2\x00\x11\x054\x88\x01\xe0\x0b\x0c\x8f=\x89=\x9cO\xd2\x0b+\xd9\x0c\x14\xe0\x0f\x10\x8fv\x8fv\xe0\x0f\x10\x8fv\x89v\x98\x17\xd2\x0f \xdc\x16\x1f\xa0&\xa8\x11\xaf\x16\xa9\x16\xa8\x08\xf0\x00\x021,\xf0\x00\x02!-\xf3\x00\x02\x17.\xf0\x00\x02\x11.\xf1\x06\x00\r\x15\xe0\x0b\x0c\x8f6\x896\x98\x17\xd4\x0b \xd8\x0f\x10\x8f}\x89}\xa4\x0e\xd2\x0f.\xb01\xb79\xb19\xc4\x07\xd23G\xdc\x16\x1f\xa0(\xa81\xaf6\xa96\xa9*\xf0\x00\x015C\x01\xf0\x00\x01!D\x01\xf3\x00\x01\x17E\x01\xf0\x00\x01\x11E\x01\xe4\x1e%\xa0d\xafF\xa9F\xd3\x1e3\x88G\x97F\x91F\x8bO\xf1#\x11\x054\xf00\x00\x0c\x10\x8f>\x8a>\xd1\x0b$\x98G\xd1\x0b$\xd0\x04$\x94hR))t\x94R\x94cdataclasses\n__dict__\nhsNNt\x94R\x94}\x94}\x94(h\x10}\x94h[\x8c#Foo.bar.<locals>.TestClass._replace\x94u\x86\x94b\x8c\x08__repr__\x94hF(hH(C\x12\x04\x02@\x01\n\x01\x02\x01"\x01\x02\x01\x10\x02"\x01\x06\xff\x94K\x01K\x00K\x00K\x03K\x05K\x13C\xd6>\x02\x95\x00[\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x005\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00[\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00R\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"\x005\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004\x02n\x01U\x01T\x03;\x00a\x01\x00\x00g\x01T\x03R\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x015\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x1e\x00T\x04"\x00U\x005\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00n\x02T\x03R\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x015\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00U\x02$\x00!\x00T\x03R\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x015\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00f\x00=\x03\x1f\x00f\x01\x94N\x8c\x03...\x94\x86\x94(\x8c\x02id\x94\x8c\x07_thread\x94\x8c\tget_ident\x94\x8c\x03add\x94\x8c\x07discard\x94t\x94hM\x8c\x03key\x94\x8c\x06result\x94\x87\x94hr\x8c\x07wrapper\x94\x8c _recursive_repr.<locals>.wrapper\x94K\xffCg\xf8\x80\x00\xe4\x0e\x10\x90\x14\x8bh\x9c\x07\xd7\x18)\xd2\x18)\xd3\x18+\xd0\x0e+\x88\x03\xd8\x0b\x0e\x90,\xd2\x0b\x1e\xd8\x13\x18\xd8\x08\x14\xd7\x08\x18\xd1\x08\x18\x98\x13\xd4\x08\x1d\xf0\x02\x03\t&\xd9\x15"\xa04\xd3\x15(\x88F\xe0\x0c\x18\xd7\x0c \xd1\x0c \xa0\x13\xd4\x0c%\xd8\x0f\x15\x88\r\xf8\xf0\x03\x00\r\x19\xd7\x0c \xd1\x0c \xa0\x13\xd5\x0c%\xfa\x94C\x0b\xba\x08A\x15\x00\xc1\x15\x13A(\x03\x94\x8c\x0crepr_running\x94\x8c\ruser_function\x94\x86\x94)t\x94R\x94}\x94\x8c\x08__name__\x94h\x0fsh~Nh\x00\x8c\x0c_create_cell\x94\x93\x94N\x85\x94R\x94h\x98N\x85\x94R\x94\x86\x94t\x94R\x94}\x94\x8c\x0b__wrapped__\x94hF(hH(C\x02\x02\x01\x94K\x01K\x00K\x00K\x01K\x06K\x13Cl\x95\x00U\x00R\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00R\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00S\x01U\x00R\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00<\x02\x0e\x00S\x02U\x00R\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00<\x02\x0e\x00S\x033\x06$\x00\x94(N\x8c\x06(val1=\x94\x8c\x07, val2=\x94\x8c\x01)\x94t\x94(hmh[h\x12h\x16t\x94hM\x85\x94hOh~\x8c\x1f__create_fn__.<locals>.__repr__\x94K\x02C.\x80\x00\xd8\x0c\x10\x8fN\x89N\xd7\x0c\'\xd1\x0c\'\xd0\x0b(\xa8\x06\xa8t\xafy\xa9y\xa9m\xb87\xc04\xc79\xc19\xc1-\xc8q\xd0\tQ\xd0\x02Q\x94hR))t\x94R\x94c__builtin__\n__main__\nh~NNt\x94R\x94}\x94}\x94(h\x10}\x94h[h\xaau\x86\x94bs}\x94(h\x10h\xb2h[\x8c#Foo.bar.<locals>.TestClass.__repr__\x94u\x86\x94bh\x95(h\x96h\x1dh\x1aN\x8c\x0b__package__\x94\x8c\x00\x94\x8c\n__loader__\x94\x8c\x1a_frozen_importlib_external\x94\x8c\x10SourceFileLoader\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94(h3h\x1d\x8c\x04path\x94hrub\x8c\x08__spec__\x94\x8c\x11_frozen_importlib\x94\x8c\nModuleSpec\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94(h3h\x1d\x8c\x06loader\x94h\xbd\x8c\x06origin\x94hr\x8c\x0cloader_state\x94N\x8c\x1asubmodule_search_locations\x94N\x8c\x19_uninitialized_submodules\x94]\x94\x8c\r_set_fileattr\x94\x88\x8c\x07_cached\x94\x8c8c:\\Python313\\Lib\\__pycache__\\dataclasses.cpython-313.pyc\x94\x8c\r_initializing\x94\x89ub\x8c\x08__file__\x94hr\x8c\n__cached__\x94h\xce\x8c\x0c__builtins__\x94cbuiltins\n__dict__\n\x8c\x02re\x94h\x00\x8c\x0e_import_module\x94\x93\x94h\xd3\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x03sys\x94h\xd5\x8c\x03sys\x94\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x04copy\x94h\xd5h\xdc\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x05types\x94h\xd5h\xdf\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x07inspect\x94h\xd5h\xe2\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x07keyword\x94h\xd5h\xe5\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\tfunctools\x94h\xd5h\xe8\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\titertools\x94h\xd5h\xeb\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x03abc\x94h\xd5h\xee\x85\x94R\x94h\x84h\xd5h\x84\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x0cFunctionType\x94h\x04\x8c\nLambdaType\x94\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x0cGenericAlias\x94h\xdf\x8c\x0cGenericAlias\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x07__all__\x94]\x94(\x8c\tdataclass\x94\x8c\x05field\x94h/\x8c\x13FrozenInstanceError\x94\x8c\x07InitVar\x94\x8c\x07KW_ONLY\x94hl\x8c\x06fields\x94\x8c\x06asdict\x94\x8c\x07astuple\x94\x8c\x0emake_dataclass\x94\x8c\x07replace\x94\x8c\x0cis_dataclass\x94eh\xfeh\x1dh\xfe\x93\x94\x8c\x1a_HAS_DEFAULT_FACTORY_CLASS\x94h\x1dj\x08\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x14_HAS_DEFAULT_FACTORY\x94cdataclasses\n_HAS_DEFAULT_FACTORY\n\x8c\r_MISSING_TYPE\x94h\x1dj\x0b\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94hlcdataclasses\nMISSING\n\x8c\r_KW_ONLY_TYPE\x94h\x1dj\r\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94j\x00\x01\x00\x00cdataclasses\nKW_ONLY\n\x8c\x0f_EMPTY_METADATA\x94h>\x8c\x0b_FIELD_BASE\x94h\x1dj\x10\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x06_FIELD\x94cdataclasses\n_FIELD\nhicdataclasses\n_FIELD_CLASSVAR\nhkcdataclasses\n_FIELD_INITVAR\nhgh-\x8c\x07_PARAMS\x94h\x1c\x8c\x0f_POST_INIT_NAME\x94\x8c\r__post_init__\x94\x8c\x15_MODULE_IDENTIFIER_RE\x94h\xd3\x8c\x08_compile\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x1b^(?:\\s*(\\w+)\\s*\\.)?\\s*(\\w+)\x94K \x86\x94R\x94\x8c\r_ATOMIC_TYPES\x94(h\x07h\x04\x8c\x08property\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x04\x8c\x07complex\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x15h\x04\x8c\x0cEllipsisType\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x04\x8c\x05float\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x19h\x04\x8c\x08CodeType\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x04\x8c\x04bool\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x04\x8c\x12NotImplementedType\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x04\x8c\x08NoneType\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x04\x8c\x11BuiltinMethodType\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\xf6h\x04\x8c\x05range\x94\x85\x94R\x94h\x04\x8c\x05bytes\x94\x85\x94R\x94\x91\x94\x8c\x0f_recursive_repr\x94h\x1dj?\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94h\xffh\x1dh\xff\x93\x94h/h0h\x1eh\x1fh\xfdh\x1dh\xfd\x93\x94\x8c\x15_fields_in_init_order\x94h\x1djC\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\n_tuple_str\x94h\x1djE\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\n_create_fn\x94h\x1djG\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\r_field_assign\x94h\x1djI\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0b_field_init\x94h\x1djK\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0b_init_param\x94h\x1djM\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x08_init_fn\x94h\x1djO\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x08_repr_fn\x94h\x1djQ\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x14_frozen_get_del_attr\x94h\x1djS\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x07_cmp_fn\x94h\x1djU\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x08_hash_fn\x94h\x1djW\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0c_is_classvar\x94h\x1djY\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0b_is_initvar\x94h\x1dj[\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0b_is_kw_only\x94h\x1dj]\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x08_is_type\x94h\x1dj_\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\n_get_field\x94h\x1dja\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\r_set_qualname\x94h\x1djc\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x12_set_new_attribute\x94h\x1dje\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0e_hash_set_none\x94h\x1djg\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\t_hash_add\x94h\x1dji\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0f_hash_exception\x94h\x1djk\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0c_hash_action\x94}\x94((\x89\x89\x89\x89t\x94N(\x89\x89\x89\x88t\x94N(\x89\x89\x88\x89t\x94N(\x89\x89\x88\x88t\x94N(\x89\x88\x89\x89t\x94jh\x01\x00\x00(\x89\x88\x89\x88t\x94N(\x89\x88\x88\x89t\x94jj\x01\x00\x00(\x89\x88\x88\x88t\x94N(\x88\x89\x89\x89t\x94jj\x01\x00\x00(\x88\x89\x89\x88t\x94jl\x01\x00\x00(\x88\x89\x88\x89t\x94jj\x01\x00\x00(\x88\x89\x88\x88t\x94jl\x01\x00\x00(\x88\x88\x89\x89t\x94jj\x01\x00\x00(\x88\x88\x89\x88t\x94jl\x01\x00\x00(\x88\x88\x88\x89t\x94jj\x01\x00\x00(\x88\x88\x88\x88t\x94jl\x01\x00\x00u\x8c\x0e_process_class\x94h\x1dj\x7f\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x13_dataclass_getstate\x94h\x1dj\x81\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x13_dataclass_setstate\x94h\x1dj\x83\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\n_get_slots\x94h\x1dj\x85\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\n_add_slots\x94h\x1dj\x87\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94h\xfch\x1dh\xfc\x93\x94j\x01\x01\x00\x00h\x1dj\x01\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x16_is_dataclass_instance\x94h\x1dj\x8b\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94j\x06\x01\x00\x00h\x1dj\x06\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94j\x02\x01\x00\x00h\x1dj\x02\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\r_asdict_inner\x94h\x1dj\x8f\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94j\x03\x01\x00\x00h\x1dj\x03\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94\x8c\x0e_astuple_inner\x94h\x1dj\x92\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94j\x04\x01\x00\x00h\x1dj\x04\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94j\x05\x01\x00\x00h\x1dj\x05\x01\x00\x00\x93\x94hshxu0\x8c\x06__eq__\x94hF(hH(C\x06\x02\x012\x01r\x01\x94K\x02K\x00K\x00K\x02K\x02K\x13C\xb2\x95\x00U\x01R\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x00R\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00L\x00a9\x00\x00U\x00R\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x01R\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:H\x00\x00=\x01(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00a\x19\x00\x00 \x00U\x00R\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x01R\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:H\x00\x00$\x00[\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00$\x00\x94N\x85\x94(hmh\x12h\x16\x8c\x0eNotImplemented\x94t\x94hM\x8c\x05other\x94\x86\x94hOj\x96\x01\x00\x00\x8c\x1d__create_fn__.<locals>.__eq__\x94K\x02C=\x80\x00\xd8\x05\n\x87_\x81_\x98\x04\x9f\x0e\x99\x0e\xd2\x05&\xd8\n\x0e\x8f)\x89)\x90U\x97Z\x91Z\xd1\n\x1f\xd7\n9\xa0D\xa7I\xa1I\xa8u\xafz\xa9z\xd1$9\xd0\x039\xdc\t\x17\xd0\x02\x17\x94hR))t\x94R\x94c__builtin__\n__main__\nj\x96\x01\x00\x00NNt\x94R\x94}\x94}\x94(h\x10}\x94h[\x8c!Foo.bar.<locals>.TestClass.__eq__\x94u\x86\x94b\x8c\x08__hash__\x94N\x8c\x0e__match_args__\x94h\x12h\x16\x86\x94ut\x94R\x94\x8c\x08builtins\x94\x8c\x07getattr\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x04dill\x94\x8c\x05_dill\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x08_setattr\x94j\xae\x01\x00\x00\x8c\x07setattr\x94\x93\x94\x87\x94R\x94h\x9c\x8c\rcell_contents\x94h\xaf\x87\x94R0j\xb8\x01\x00\x00h\x9aj\xb9\x01\x00\x00\x8f\x94\x87\x94R0j\xb6\x01\x00\x00j\xad\x01\x00\x00h[\x8c\x1aFoo.bar.<locals>.TestClass\x94\x87\x94R0.'))

This outputs:
<class '__main__.Foo.bar.<locals>.TestClass'>


Err… you could just return TestClass…?! Why serialise it?

Because the OP asks for a serialization/deserialization solution. I've updated my answer by splitting the demo into two scripts so that it is clear that the deserialization can take place in a separate session.

@deceze It's indeed just a minimum working example where the final use case is serialization and deserialization!

@blhsing Thanks for the suggestion using dill. I will look into the source code and check, how it's done in there (in the end, they somehow need to do it there).
